# How can I rotate and object with mouse inputs

Tags: c#, math, rotation

I am trying to rotate an object with a mouse click and rotate with the mouse movement. the code I'm using works when I click and drag my mouse, the object rotates towards and moves with the mouse. Rather than that, I want it to rotate just with the mouse like a volume dial.

How do rotate the object like a dial?

```
Sstart = e.GetPosition(dial);
        
        if (dial.IsStylusCaptured)
        {               
            AngleRot = Math.Atan2((Y - Sstart.Y) , (X - Sstart.X));
            radAngle = AngleRot / Math.PI * 180 + 180;
            radAngle = radAngle - AthetaD;
            di.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(radAngle + 90);                     
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you need to use a simple function that receives a point to rotate (px, py), the center point of rotation (cx, cy) and the angle of rotation (alpha) and returns the resulting point, something like this: `rotatePoint(px, py, cx, cy, alpha)` ?

Comment: I Updated my post with some pictures to give you an example

Comment: Well, I still don't undertand the situation and the pictures don't help. Let's start from the beginning. You have a point with coordinates x1 and y1. Right? You have another point with coordinates x2, y2. You have an angle to rotate the first point relatively to the second. Once you rotated, you have new coordinates for the first point. Then you can apply another rotation to the new coordinates and so on. Is my description correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. x1 and y1 are mentioned in another one of my lines above this one. x2 and y2 are being generated during the movement because they are based on user input. So yes your description is accurate. I think that's actually the issue I'm having here, I think my rotated angle isn't setting as the first point

Comment: You need to explain in the question what the circle and triangle and lines represent and what the intent is.

Answer (score 1):

Let current direction vector is `(cx, cy)`.

In the beginning set it into `(1,0)` or another needed value.

When you rotated dial, you have new direction

```
nx = X - Sstart.X
ny = Y - Sstart.Y
```

To rotate current direction vector to new one, you need to calculate relative angle. This approach uses cross product and dot product of vectors. Perhaps you'll need to change sign of the first expression

```
Angle =  Math.Atan2(nx * cy - ny * cx, cx * nx + cy * ny)
..apply rotation by Angle
```

After rotation remember current direction to use it later

```
cx = nx
cy = ny
```